# How to get the max from row's elements in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains a single column `Positive Dispatch`,

```
index Positive Dispatch
  0        a,c
  1         b
  2        a,b
```

Each keyword has its own value:

```
a,b,c = 12,22,11
```

I want to create a new column that contains the max of each row, for example in the first row there are `a` and `c` and between them `a` has the biggest value, which is 12 and so on:

```
Positive Dispatch  Max
    a,c             12
     b              22
    a,b             22
```

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
dic1 = {
    'a': [12,0,22],
    'b': [0,13,22],
    'c': [12,0,0], # there can be N number of columns here for example
} # 'd': [11,22,333]

a,b,c = 12,22,11 # d will have its own value, for example d = 33
df = pd.DataFrame(dic1)
df['Positive Dispatch'] = df.gt(0).dot(df.columns + ',').str[:-1] #Creating the positive dispatch column
print(df['Positive Dispatch'].max(axis=1))
```

But this gives the error:

```
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: `Positive Dispatch` contains strings, what did you expect `max(axis=1)` to return?

Comment: yeah, it's a string but can we convert them to a variable and then compare their values?

Comment: The Max column is the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

create a dict then calculate max according to the key and value of the dictionary by using `split()`+`max()`+`map()`:

```
d={'a':a,'b':b,'c':c}
df['Max']=df['Positive Dispatch'].str.split(',').map(lambda x:max([d.get(y) for y in x]))
#for more columns use applymap() in place of map() and logic remains same
```

**OR**
If you have more columns like 'Dispatch' then use:

```
d={'a':a,'b':b,'c':c,'d':d}
df[['Max','Min']]=df[['Positive Dispatch','Negative Dispatch']].applymap(lambda x:max([d.get(y) for y in x.split(',')]))
```

Sample Dataframe used:

```
dic1 = {
    'a': [12,0,22],
    'b': [0,13,22],
    'c': [12,0,0], # there can be N number of columns here for example
    'd': [11,22,333]}

a,b,c,d = 12,22,11,33 # d will have its own value, for example d = 33
df = pd.DataFrame(dic1)
df['Positive Dispatch'] = df.gt(0).dot(df.columns + ',').str[:-1]
df['Negative Dispatch']=[['a,d'],['c,b,a'],['d,c']]
df['Negative Dispatch']=df['Negative Dispatch'].str.join(',')
```

output:

```
    a   b   c   Positive Dispatch   Max
0   12  0   12  a,c                 12
1   0   13  0   b                   22
2   22  22  0   a,b                 22
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but can we automate the steps for the map sections, where you mapping the values {'a':a and so on because in actual there can be n number of columns?

Comment: @Vesper yes use `apply()` or `agg()` in place of `map()`

Comment: ahh how exactly?

Comment: @Vesper try `df[(list of columns)].str.split(',').agg(lambda x:max([d.get(y) for y in x]),axis=1)`

Comment: Hey this is not working if I increase the number of columns, I inserted one more column d with some values and replace map with apply() but its giving me the error

Comment: @Vesper can you make change in your question reflecting the same and also to test code?

Comment: how can I do it for N number of columns?

Comment: @Vesper I tested for the updated dataframe map it is working

Comment: @Vesper updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**